# What is wrong with this Gradle syntax?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm just beginning to learn Groovy and Gradle, and am playing around with some hello world gradle scripts.  In the following two scripts, the first one succeeds, and the second doesn't.  Can anyone explain why?  As an aside, i do realize these aren't 'standard' Gradle syntax, but they match the API.

This works:

```
task 'hello' << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}

task 'intro', dependsOn: hello << {
    println "I'm Gradle"
}
```

this fails (difference are the quotes around 'hello'): could not determine the dependencies of task ':intro'

```
task 'hello' << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}

task 'intro', dependsOn: 'hello' << {
    println "I'm Gradle"
}
```

but this works:

```
task 'hello' << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}

task('intro', dependsOn: 'hello') << {
    println "I'm Gradle"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and second snippets are both wrong. The first may not fail outright, but it doesn't have the desired outcome (task action is added to `hello` rather than `intro`). Best use a more standard syntax:

```
task hello << { ... }
task intro(dependsOn: hello) << { ... }
```

Or even better:

```
task hello {
    doLast { ... }
}

task intro {
    dependsOn hello
    doLast { ... }
}
```

The latter syntax is more regular and avoids common mistakes made when using named arguments (e.g. `dependsOn:`) and `<<`.

Comment: I didn't even realize my first example had a different output than the third.  Thanks for pointing that out.  That clears up why the parentheses are needed.  I like the syntax of your latter example.  Thanks for the fast reply.